# react dom nested route not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I am new to react and I want to do something similar to below;

```
home
home/pageone
home/pagetwo
other
```

my `App.js` has the following;

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
       <Header />
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/home' component={Homepage} />

          <Route exact path='/other' component={Other} />
          </Switch>

       <Footer />
      </div>
  </Router>
);
```

My Homepage has the following;

```
render() {
    return (
    <div class="main-wrap">
      <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
      <li className="sidebar bar">
              <Link to ={`${this.props.match.path}/pageone`}> pageone</Link>
      </li>
      </div>
      <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/pageone`} component={PageOne} />
      <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.path}`} component={HomeDefault} />
  </div>
);
```

It looks like my,

```
Route exact path={`${this.props.match.path}`} component={HomeDefault} />"
```

is working perfectly fine. It is showing the component. But,

```
Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/pageone`} component={PageOne}
```

is not working at all. I think the problem is probably very basic.
I tried to google all day and could not find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

it's because of `exact` at `Route` in your root.

```
<Route exact path='/home' component={Homepage} />
```

matches `/home/` but does not match `/home/pageone`. So it does not even render `Homepage`. Remove `exact` and everything will be fine.

```
<Route path='/home' component={Homepage} />
```